# Jquery: Index issue for rowspan

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I want to add new row at end of each Branch column to show Branch Total using Jquery. But getting an issue at the end of the page the Branch Total row is inserted before two row I am unable to fix it please see to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bablukpik/2zyg7593/3/)

The issue is the index to select next row from the current row for insert new row in the following code:

```
$('.units').each(function () {
    //console.log(++i);
    let thisUnit = $(this);
    let thisIndex = $(this).index();
    let firstColUnit;
    let secondColUnit;
    if ($(this).find('td[rowspan]').length == 2) {
        firstColUnit = $(this).find('td:eq(0)');
        secondColUnit = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
    }

    if ($(this).find('td[rowspan]').length == 3) {
        firstColUnit = $(this).find('td:eq(1)');
        secondColUnit = $(this).find('td:eq(2)');
    }

    let firstColRowspanUnit = parseInt(firstColUnit.attr('rowspan'));
    let secondColRowspanUnit = parseInt(secondColUnit.attr('rowspan'));

    nextUnit += firstColRowspanUnit;
    //nextUnit += thisUnit.index();


    // let nextUnits = thisUnit.nextUntil('.units').last();
    // let expectedRow = $('.allrow:eq('+(nextUnit-1)+')');
    let expectedRow = $('.allrow:eq(' + (nextUnit - 1) + ')');


    expectedRow.after('<tr><td colspan="6"><strong>Branch Total</strong></td></tr>');

    let s = parseInt(firstColShip.attr('rowspan'));
    let t = parseInt(firstColUnit.attr('rowspan'));
    let tt = parseInt(secondColUnit.attr('rowspan'));

    firstColShip.attr('rowspan', s + 1);
    firstColUnit.attr('rowspan', t + 1);
    secondColUnit.attr('rowspan', tt + 1);
});
```

Here is the screenshot
[image: show image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include the original HTML of the table

Comment: I have a jsfiddle @Fr0zenFyr

link https://jsfiddle.net/bablukpik/2zyg7593/3/

Answer (score 0):

I can identify the problem but I can't managed to solve it.

The 2 rows below are not taken into account because they don't have a rowspan greater than 1.

If you remove them all works perfectly

```html
    <!--Branch Total Row-->
    <tr class="allrow">
        <!--Ship Col-->

        <!--Posting Col-->
        <td rowspan="1">HM/CAB</td>
        <!--Branch Col-->
        <td rowspan="1">STEWARD</td>
        <td>L/STW</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>

    <!--Branch Total Row-->
    <tr class="allrow">
        <!--Ship Col-->

        <!--Posting Col-->
        <td rowspan="1">HM/CAB</td>
        <!--Branch Col-->
        <td rowspan="1">TOPASS</td>
        <td>TOP-I</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
```